# A native cross-browser solution to Animate SVG points

Tags: animation, svg, cross-browser, web-standards, smil

CSS is great for transforming and animating elements in all types of ways. But for fine-tuned path control / animating individual points of a path etc - something like [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) or the many JS animation libraries exist.

1. Why is [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) being depreciated if it's a native solution?
2. Are there any Polyfills/hacks to get [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) working in IE or Edge as
   it is the only major browser without any support?

Comment: 1. Who says SMIL is deprecated? Chrome used to but changed its mind. 2. https://leunen.me/fakesmile/

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah I see you have a point. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL